# Error While Uploading in JAVA "message[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!]"

Tags: java, file-upload, dwr, fileoutputstream

I am trying to upload a image file and zip file. First i have started with image upload, it gave me `message[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!` Error. But, still it uploaded the image. Then i have added code to upload zip file. Now also i am getting same error. But, unlike last time, the image only getting uploaded and its size is 0 bytes.

I am using DWR to bring the data to server,

**DWR Script:**

```
function uploadImage(){
var image = dwr.util.getValue("uploadImage");
var file = dwr.util.getValue("uploadFile");
dwr.util.setValue("uploadImage", null);
dwr.util.setValue("uploadFile", null);
DataUpload.uploadData(image, file, function(data){
    if(data != null){
        $("#imgURL").html("<p>Upload Completed!!!</p>");
        $("#imgURL").append("Location: "+data.path1);
        $("#zipURL").html("<p>Upload Completed!!!</p>");
        $("#zipURL").append("Location: "+data.path2);
    }
});
```

}

This the CODE i am trying.

```
public class DataUpload {
private static String DATA_STORE_LOC = "D:/Uploaded/Trials/";
public Path uploadData(InputStream image, InputStream file) throws IOException{
Path path = new Path();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(image);
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
String dat = format.format(date);
System.out.println(dat);
try {
    path.setPath1(DATA_STORE_LOC+dat+".jpg");
    System.out.println(DATA_STORE_LOC+dat+".jpg");
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File(DATA_STORE_LOC+dat+".jpg"));
    System.out.println(true);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    File f2 = new File(DATA_STORE_LOC+dat+".zip");
    path.setPath2(DATA_STORE_LOC+dat+".zip");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
    while((len = file.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    file.close();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
return path;

}
```

**Update:** Console Log

```
49 //System.out.println(dat);
D:/Uploaded/Trials/49.jpg //System.out.println(DATA_STORE_LOC+dat+".jpg");
745859 [18820833@qtp-7494106-7] WARN  org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallMarshaller  - --Erroring: batchId[1] message[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!]
```

**Final Update**

I have tried to upload zip file alone itself by commenting the other parts. Its get upload. But its size also zero bytes!!!

Where I am going wrong????

Any suggesstions!!!

Comment: where do you get this exception? can you give more details about the stacktrace output?

Comment: @Abdel Olakara: I just updated something about log.

Comment: you should perhaps add that you are using DWR and include the code that uses it.

Comment: @pjesi: You found it. I thought the above code will be enough to guide me. Ok, now i will update the question again. Thanks.

Comment: I thought it was simple one and pro's can easily find my mistake. But the answer rate makes me to search about it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get the binary value of a file in an upload field. The value of `dwr.util.getValue("uploadImage");` is either the path of the file or empty if the browser doesn't let you read the local file path. So basically you are submitting text or nothing but are trying to read it as a file.

I once implemented an upload file in a DWR application but I used an iframe to handle the file uploading functionality. Recent browsers (FF3.6+, Safari4+, Chrome) do support sending files with XHR but don't count on your users to be using one them.

You could use an library such as [FileUploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) to handle this for you, they even have a Java example for the server side. It uses XHR if available and falls back on an iframe workaround.

Comment: I have already mentioned that, i was able to upload images with same code above. I tested it. Thats working. Like the same way i got the zip file too. I read it in a ZipInputStream reader. Can you tell me how to store it as a ZIP file in server. All of the examples are about reading a zip or creating zip file from a text file. My issue is i have a read a zip file, and its in ZipInputStream and finally i want to save it in some location. Shall you tell me how to do that!!! Anyway thanks for your reply. I was waiting for 6 hours to get an answer. Thanks again!!!

Comment: We can get the upload file url by dwr.util.getValue(). My problem is caused by version mis match. Thanks for you reply and sorry for wasting your time.